What do the CPU usage numbers in plasma-systemmonitor mean and why are they so high?
When opening plasma-systemmonitor I get really weird CPU usage numbers that total to more than 100%. I tried to show all kinds of different CPU usages but I can't seem to find the one that shows the percentage of the total CPU load but couldn't find it.

I added a sensor to my desktop that monitors the total CPU load and that one seems to be correct (meaning it doesn't go over 100%)

How can I see which process takes up how much percentage of the total CPU capacity in plasma-systemmonitor?

It probably is a per-core utilisation. So add up all values and divide by the number of processor cores your system has. If it is less than 100% then probably this is the reason. It could also be because of frequency scaling but for this I don't know how to find out.
